# Return a View with a Variable in laravel using vsmoraes/laravel-pdf package

Tags: php, html, laravel

I'm in need of printing data from the database using the vsmoraes/laravel-pdf package but can't be able to pass on the data into a view. This is my function in the controller

```
public function print($id)
    {
        $item1 = Order::find($id);
        $html = view('pdfs.example')->render();
        return PDF::load($html)->show();
    }
```

I have tried out this but i get a response of "Trying to get property of a non-object"

```
public function print($id)
        {
            $item1 = Order::find($id);
            $html = view('pdfs.example')->withItem1($item1)->render();
            return PDF::load($html)->show();
        }
```

This is my route

```
Route::get('/pdf/view/{id}', 'OrderController@print')->name('prt');
```

What could be the solution?

Comment: BTW `$item1 != $item`,What variable you are using in `pdfs.example` ?

Comment: just corrected it, was a mistake in typing the question

Comment: ok What variable you are using in `pdfs.example` ?

Comment: {{$item1->item}}

Comment: Try using `->with('item1',$item1)` instead `->withItem1($item1)`

Comment: Yes it has worked.@C2486 Thanks alot